# Generating QR code of very big file?

Tags: bash, gpg, qr-code

I want to generate a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) of my 4096-bit armored [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) private key. The key is so big, the program `qrencode` seems to fail because of its size.

```
$ gpg --export-secret-keys --armor > ~/private.key
$ ./qrencode -o test.png < ~/private.key
```

Result:

> Failed to encode the input data: Numerical result out of range

How can I make that happen? Are there alternative programs to qrencode which can handle a very big GPG key? I want to print it on paper as [this security.SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51776/83032) suggested.

---

The comments of @geruetzel and @ cuonglm are addressing [this version of my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/280222/1).

Comment: Remove `<`, the command is `qrencode -o test.png -t png "$( cat private.key)"`

Comment: @cuonglm sry, didn't realize that mistake. I updated my answer.

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: are you coming up against the designed size limit for QR codes?  consider searching down to "Maximum character storage capacity" on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: @Theophrastus i just found it out myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error message already gives a hint as to what's wrong!

Your one-liner is providing the actual file content as filename to the qrencode program. Hence the error message.

Try `qrencode -o test.png -t png < private.key`.

You should take a look at shell input-output redirection. For example, *[I/O Redirection](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php)*.

I see that you too have found your way to the developers GitHub repository of qrencode :) There is an explanation why a 4096-bit key cannot be encoded as a QR code:

> qrencode is encoding your private GPG key as 8 bit (binary|utf-8), because the key is not pure alphanumeric. It contains special character. the alphanumeric mode only supports those special character .(%*+-./:).
>   So the maximum GPG key can only be 2953 char long.

From https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/issues/31

Comment: Sry, i didn't realize it that - but still It seems that my gpg key is too big for Qrencode. (I updated my answer to address that issue)

Answer (score 11):

The key could not be encoded as a single QR code. But two (or more) could work.

- Export your key (as before):

  ```
  gpg --export-secret-keys --armor > private.key
  ```
- Generate files of a maximun size of 2500 byte:

  ```
  split -C 2500 private.key splitkey-
  ```
- Convert each to one QR file (same name with extension `.qr`)

  ```
  for file in splitkey-??; do
      <"$file" qrencode -s 3 -d 150 -o "$file".qr
  done
  ```

When it is needed to recover the key. You can scan each QR code which will each produce an string. Just concatenate each string in sequence of the filenames. Lets assume that the result key is stored in the file `newkey`.

And you may test that the internal CRC-24 of the key checks out.

```
 gpg --dearmor newkey >/dev/null
```

If there is no error message, the key file has been reconstructed correctly.

Comment: This is what I was thinking also, why not split the key into three pieces, then create three qr codes that can be scanned and reassembled.

Comment: Why do you specify the dpi in the `qrencode` command? I'm curious what purpose that serves. Is it necessary?

Comment: Just FYI for future readers, `2500` might be sufficiently small to generate the a QR code, but a QR code that dense is very hard to scan with a phone. It's probable that you can still read it by taking a picture and running it through a command line utility like [those found in the arch aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&C=0&SeB=nd&K=QR+Code&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go) but most android apps will have trouble with it. It's not too much more work to set the byte limit to `1000` on the `split` operation and just generate a few more QR codes. Then it scans like a dream.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass the options `-Sv40` (40 is a version), `qrencode` will automatically create multiple images for input that's too large.  For example:

```
qrencode -o private.png -t png -Sv 40 < private.key
```

will output `private-01.png`, `private-02.png`, and `private-03.png`.

Comment: the problem with the generated qr codes is that they are too dense and phones don't seem to be able to parse them

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that this is not possible.

```
% wc -c ~/private.key
6709 /home/toogley/private.key
```

(`-c` counts characters.)

to cite from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage):

max characters for alphanumerical characters: **4,296.**

Comment: Yes and even this limit does not apply to your key - see my answer's update!

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [paperkey](http://www.jabberwocky.com/software/paperkey/), which is designed to take a GPG secret key, and transform it into a sequence of bytes that can be printed out on paper.  The secret key can be subsequently recovered from the text after scanning it or keying it in.

There's also a discussion of [various ways of archiving data on paper](http://www.dansdata.com/gz094.htm) which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you minimize your key before encoding it.

`gpg --export --export-options export-minimal`

Depending on how you've used your key in the past, it may save you old binding signatures.